# omnet tictioc - opp_makemake error

Tags: omnet++

I am practising on onmet tictoc , while running  the command (opp_makemake ) , the error message appears (  'perl' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file).  please advice

Comment: Additional details would help. Which OMNeT++ version and which operating system are you using?

Comment: It sounds like you need to install perl. Depending on your operating system this may be something like `sudo apt-get install perl` or `yum install perl`